# Convert HTML into image using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using `html2canvas` for converting `div` into `image`. This is working
fine expect in **google font effect** Here is image you can see how it removes
The effect from text.

[image]

Here is a code which I'm using for this.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome to canvas to HTML</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton
                &effect=ice">

    <script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<div id="canvas">
    <span class="font-effect-ice" style="font-family: Anton; font-size:50px">This is some text.</span>
</div>
<button onclick="generateImage()">Click</button>

<div id="img-out"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Below is javascript code.

```
function generateImage(){

var imageContainer = $('#canvas');

html2canvas(imageContainer, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            theCanvas = canvas;
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);

            // Convert and download as image
            $("#img-out").append(canvas);
            // Clean up
            //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
        }
});     

}
```

Can anyone please tell me why this is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've experimented with the code. I believe it happens because the ice effect is in fact an image which is overlaid on the text using -webkit-mask-image.

Meaning it is not exactly part of the text but instead an image on top of the text. HTML2canvas uses the content inside the canvas div, not any images above it.

Comment: `HtmlToCanvas` is not able to convert images. Thanks.